# Use ACF field value (color) for Post Card Template using Avada page builder for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom post type in WordPress using the ACF plugin. To this post type, I have added a custom fields group with ACF. In this fields group, I have some text fields, numeric fields, and even a color picker field.

These fields are used for a Post Card template, in which I define a basic template that is used for all posts. Within this template, I can refer to these ACF fields in relation to content or images. Images and content are displayed dynamically, referencing the ACF fields.

I would like to use the ACF field 'color' to dynamically style template elements like column backgrounds, borders, and so on. However, dynamic coloring is not supported.

[image: Image Description]

Does anyone have an idea on how I can set the colors of elements based on ACF field values?

Comment: It seems that Elementor Pro Page builder offers this functionality: https://www.wppagebuilders.com/custom-color-for-individual-blog-post-title-in-wordpress/